# How to reference resources for a global bash script with a relative path

Tags: bash

my global bash script calls python scripts and references json template files. I'll designate these as resources. I'd like to reference these with a path relative to the bash script. How may I do this? The problem is when I call the script from another directory it doesn't see resources. It only works if I put resources in this directory or if I put an absolute path for all resources.

Comment: You can use `dirname $0` to get the directory containing your script, or `pwd` to get the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is executed rather than `source`d, it may be worth looking at the `$BASH_SOURCE` variable.  This holds the path to the current executeable.